# call service method in another method and get result

Tags: node.js, oop, nestjs

I'm new with NesJs and OOP .

I've created a simple API that it's `controller` is like this .

```js
@Controller('api')
export class UsersController {
    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) { }

    @Get('user/:id')
    async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
        return this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
    }

    @Get('test/:id')
    async test(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<User> {
        return this.usersService.testMethod(id);
    }
}
```

and this is `userSerive`

```js
export class UsersService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(User.name) private readonly userModel: Model<UserDocument>,
    ) { }

    async findOne(id: string): Promise<User> {
        try {
            const data = await fetch(process.env.SOURCE_URI + 'users/' + id)
            const json = await data.json()
            return json.data

        } catch (error) { return error }
    }

    async testMethod(id: string): Promise<User> {
          const user=await this.findOne(id)
          console.log('found user', user) // return user undefined
          return user
    }
    async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
        try {
            let user = await this.userModel.findOne({ email: 
             createUserDto.email })
            if (!user) {
                user = await this.userModel.create(createUserDto);
            }
            return user;

        } catch (error) {

        }
    }

}
```

as you see I've called `findOne` method in `testMethod`

and problem is here

the problem is that if I call `user/:id` route it works perfectly and returns user info

But if if I call `test` route , It **doesn't work**

**where** is the problem and how can I **fix** it?

Comment: can you include the `create` function please ?

Comment: now please include your `userModel` class if you don't mind

Comment: Are you certain the `id` you're passing it is coming in correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You have to get advantage of the model you've imported since its `SchemaFactory` for a class that extends Document so there is no need for this:

```js
const user= await this.userModel.findById(id)
```